# What is secp256k1 and can we have a post quantum cryptography with that?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, secp256k1

Please detail secp256k1 and its role in a public key cryptography. Please explain can we use it into a post-quantum cryptography and how can we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`secp256k1`](https://neuromancer.sk/std/secg/secp256k1) is a commonly used curve in elliptic curve cryptography
- [elliptic curve cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography) is an approach to realize public key cryptography, mainly known for its efficiency and security
- [Post-quantum cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-quantum_cryptography) is believed to be secure against quantum computers. There are various approaches to realize post-quantum security, e.g. latticed-based, hash-based, multivariate-based etc. NIST has already selected some post-quantum signature algorithms as standards: https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/post-quantum-cryptography/selected-algorithms-2022
- Elliptic curve cryptography is believed to be vulnerable against quantum computers
- Since elliptic curve cryptography is not secure against quantum computers, there are various patch solutions: One is to combine post-quantum signature schemes with elliptic curve based signature in a 'hybrid mode'. e.g. https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/Events/2022/fourth-pqc-standardization-conference/documents/papers/a-flexible-shared-hardware-accelerator-pqc2022.pdf. Also, it's possible to simply use a post-quantum algorithm, but currently it's not highly recommended